# Stop redirect_to and link_to from controller method ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

May be my question would be awkward but i am new to ruby.
I am working on a project. My task is that when in table status has value "submitted" then the link "advance_status" shouldn't be clicked or redirected or render.
I know logic will be implemented in controller but what should i write in my advance_status method in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you can do something like:

```
def advance_status
  if thing.status == 'submitted'
    # Redirect to previous page if status is 'submitted'
    session[:alert] << 'This is not allowed'
    redirect_to :back and return
  end

  # Other code...
end
```

Comment: Isn't there a way so that the link behind the Advance Status could be disabled. I mean if user still clicks on it so it may not render nor redirect nor page refresh, just like clicking on a simple text in a website

Comment: Well, you can disable or hide a link, but a user can still enter the URL manually and visit the page. Therefore, you have to have a check in the controller action.

Comment: thanks zwippie i just changed session[:alert] to flash[:alert] and it worked perfectly...thanks